# Forgotten password for Postgresql - Resetting password - Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, postgresql

I used blog entry by Robby on Rails site:

http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2008/01/22/installing-ruby-on-rails-and-postgresql-on-os-x-third-edition

Got to the end, but when I tried accessing the pg database I was denied.

I've tried to change pg_hba.config file to trust so that I can gain access anyway (without a password), but proved fruitless.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart postgresql after you alter the pg_hba.config file to make sure your changes are read. Next, type

```
psql -U myUser template1
```

in a terminal, where `myUser`is the name of the user running the postgres proces. That should make you log in as administrator. Next, in the psql session, write

```
ALTER USER realUser PASSWORD 'myNewPassword';
```

in order to reset the password. Here `realUser`is the user of the database you are trying to connect to.

Comment: After 'psql -U myUser template1' I get 'WARNING: password file "/Users/sajeev86/.pgpass" has world or group read access; permission should be u=rw (0600)' Then get asked for a password I do not know.

Comment: For some reason your file permissions are incorrect. Fix it by typing "chmod 0600 /Users/sajeev86/.pgpass" in the terminal (not in psql).

Comment: It asks for my password for the user like before.

Comment: @someName I get the same situation as Sajeev.